# visual studio This file does not have a program associated with it

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

Anyone can help me
I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 and OpenCV  when  I am trying to run code this error is appearing:

> This file does not have a program associated with it for performing
>   this action please install a program or, if one already installed,
>   create an association in the Default Programs in the control panel.

the code i was running :

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    if( argc != 2){
        cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread(argv[1], IMREAD_COLOR); // Read the file

    if(! image.data ) // Check for invalid input{
        cout << "Could not open or find the image" << endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );   
    imshow( "Display window", image ); // Show our image inside it.
    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the including for : #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
                            #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
                            #include <iostream>

Comment: Sorry please edit your question with how you are running this program, also check you your active project (this will be in bold in your Solution Explorer view) settings, right-click on it and see what is shown under Debugging and for 'Command' and 'Working Directory'

Comment: It compile without error?

Comment: for EdChum  i running it via (Debug->Build solution) and for 'Command' there is not any selection ,for 'Working Directory" --> $(ProjectDir)

Comment: For Tom A yes it compile without error

Answer (score 1):

The issue could be (for lack of distinct information) that your Startup Project does not generate an executable.

If you have a project which creates a Dll or Lib file set as you startup project, then VS cannot run a file for that project, producing that error.

### Changing the Startup Project:

As [EdChum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704848/edchum) Mentioned, the Startup Project will be in bold in the project explorer. If this is not the project that produces the executable you wish to run, **right-click the correct project** in the project explorer then **"Set as Startup Project"**

[Setting startup project example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEWUm.jpg)

Microsoft also has a more detailed explanation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1awth7y.aspx).